# How to stop mono-xsp4 running on terminal?

Tags: command-line, mono

I'am working with Asp.NET MVC on Ubuntu 16.04.

To run my Asp pages I use **mono-xsp4** that can be installed running:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-xsp4
```

Then I run the command **xsp4** on the folder I want to serve, and the output is:

```
eleandro@e200:~$ xsp4
xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /home/eleandro
Listening on port: 9000 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.
```

Ok... Its running. But I can't stop it!!! I have tried stop it using CTRL+C, CTRL+D, CTRL+X, backspace, ESC, Etc... Nothing works!

The only way I have founded to stop it is closing the whole terminal.

Is there another way to stop mono-xsp4 running on terminal?

Comment: Did you hit return a.k.a. enter?

Comment: I didn't! Tried now, it worked! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says hit `Return` to stop server. I just did that and it stopped, it's the key we usually call the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks!!! It was impossible to figure out that `Return` is `Enter`.